# How to iterate through all emails in folder and save contents to dictionary - Python

Tags: python, outlook

Hi I am a bit new to Python and its functions :) I need to iterate through a folder of lots of emails and dump the contents to a dictionary. I have written this code but the dictionary function fails.

```
import win32com.client #to initiate Outlook; read emails
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os

from io import StringIO

#folder path for where the emails are saved
folder = r'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Emails'

#folder path of where results files will be saved
result_folder = r'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Result'

#open outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

#extract the emails, and get a consolidated email meta data
for email in os.listdir(folder):
    print(email)
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'Filename': [email],
        'To': [msg.To],
        'Cc': [msg.Cc],
        'From': [msg.SenderName],
        'Subject': [msg.Subject],
        'Body': [msg.body],
        'SentDateTime': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp=msg.SentOn.timestamp(), tz=msg.SentOn.tzinfo).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') 
        })
```

At this point all email subjects print on screen however the dictionary loop fails.

```
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(msg_file)
    
        #Email details saved into a dataframe
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'Filename': [email],
        'To': [msg.To],
        'Cc': [msg.Cc],
        'From': [msg.SenderName],
        'Subject': [msg.Subject],
        'Body': [msg.body],
        'SentDateTime': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp=msg.SentOn.timestamp(), tz=msg.SentOn.tzinfo).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') 
        })
```

When I run the dictionary loop I only get one result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to read emails from a folder using Outlook and dump their contents into a dictionary using Pandas. However, it seems that you are missing a few key steps to actually read the emails and extract their contents.

looking for:

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import os

#folder path for where the emails are saved
folder = r'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Emails'

#folder path of where results files will be saved
result_folder = r'C:\Users\XX\Desktop\Result'

#open outlook
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

#iterate over emails in folder
emails = []
for email_file in os.listdir(folder):
    if email_file.endswith('.msg'): #only process .msg files
        email_path = os.path.join(folder, email_file)
        msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(email_path)
        emails.append({
            'Filename': email_file,
            'To': msg.To,
            'Cc': msg.Cc,
            'From': msg.SenderName,
            'Subject': msg.Subject,
            'Body': msg.body,
            'SentDateTime': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp=msg.SentOn.timestamp(), tz=msg.SentOn.tzinfo).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        })

#convert list of dictionaries to DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(emails)

#save DataFrame to CSV
result_path = os.path.join(result_folder, 'emails.csv')
data.to_csv(result_path, index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks  so helpful. What was I missing?

Comment: You're welcome. Original code, you were using msg_file without defining it, so the OpenSharedItem() method would have raised an error. Also, you were not actually iterating through the emails in the folder; instead, you were just iterating through the files in the folder and trying to create a DataFrame for each file, which would not have worked as intended.